# Why Treeview doesn't show the hierarchy?

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I have added a treeview to my system. I could manage to show the content of the treeview. But the output is not same as I expected. Here I have added an image of the output. Please take look at it.

**aspx code**

```html
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ImageSet="XPFileExplorer"
                         NodeIndent="15">
     <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#6666AA" />
     <NodeStyle Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalPadding="2px"
              NodeSpacing="0px" VerticalPadding="10px"></NodeStyle>
     <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" />
     <SelectedNodeStyle BackColor="#B5B5B5" Font-Underline="False" HorizontalPadding="0px"
              VerticalPadding="2px" />
</asp:TreeView>
```

**C# code**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        dt=getDataObj.treeSketch();
        PopulateTreeView(dt, 0, null);
    }
}       

private void PopulateTreeView(DataTable dsParent, int parentId, TreeNode treeNode)
{
     foreach (DataRow row in dsParent.Rows)
     {
          TreeNode child = new TreeNode
          {
                Text = row["FUNCTION_NAME"].ToString(),
                Value = row["FUNCTION_CODE"].ToString()
          };
          if (parentId == 0)
          {
                TreeView1.Nodes.Add(child);
                dt = getDataObj.loadTree(child);
                PopulateTreeView(dt, int.Parse(child.Value), child);
          }
          else
          {
                treeNode.ChildNodes.Add(child);
          }
     }
 }
```

[image: TreeView image]
In here nodes in capital letters are main node and other are child nodes. Why doesn't it appear like a treeview? How to make it work?

**Query**

```
public DataTable loadTree(TreeNode child)
{
     string strQuery = @"select FUNCTION_CODE,USER_TYPE from [WEB_FUNCTIONACCESS]
                        where FUNCTION_CODE = '"+ child +"' ";

    return SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(strConnStringAppeal, CommandType.Text, strQuery).Tables[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is actually pretty obvious.

```
if (parentId == 0)
      {
            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(child);
            dt = getDataObj.loadTree(child);
            PopulateTreeView(dt, int.Parse(child.Value), child);
      }
      else
      {
            treeNode.ChildNodes.Add(child);
      }
```

So the condition is that if parentId is 0 then add a root level node, otherwise add at the child level.

Now when you call this method, `PopulateTreeView(dt, 0, null)`, the `parentId` parameter is always **0**.

Update:

I see you have a recursive call to the method, `PopulateTreeView`, given the child value. `int.Parse(child.Value)` does this always evaluate as 0?

The problem is you used the reference of `child` which gives you a TreeNode object. What you really should be using is `child.Value` which gives you a string value. Then you can append it to the query string there.

Comment: Actually this code I found on the internet. So even i don't have a proper idea about it yet

Comment: Can you debug the code locally and step through the lines?

Comment: as you think what should I do in order to make this work?

Comment: Sure I will try to debug give you a feedback. Give me few minutes

Comment: My suggestion is to pay more attention to the data sources, and see if you are really getting the correct values for `parentId` parameter

Comment: This is the query i get.  Query gets child value as parameter and it shows lik this .   
select FUNCTION_CODE,USER_TYPE from [WEB_FUNCTIONACCESS]
                            where FUNCTION_CODE = 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode'

Comment: It doesn't pass the value to the query. What should i do now?

Comment: Can you paste your code that handles getting the data source in your post? My initial thinking is that you have to do a type conversion and pass in the value.

Comment: Also, 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode' suggests that you are passing a Node object instead of string type value. You could call ChildNode.Value to get the value from that child node.

Comment: I tried to do it like that. But when it goes to the query how should I handle it in there? In the query I have added parameter as TreeNode child.  How should I change it in the query?

Comment: can you add the code from this method getDataObj.loadTree(child) into your question? How does it get implemented there?

Comment: Please check the question I have added the query

Comment: my answer updated as well. In short, use `child.Value` instead of just 'child'. Also it's worth using parameterised query to avoid potential sql injection attack.

Comment: @user6592730 let me know if my answer or comments helped or not. if solved your problem, pls mark the answer. thanks

Comment: Yes your answer helped upto a certain extent. But didn't solve the problem. I did it just adding them to aspx somehow. Thanks. Also i have voted to your answer

Comment: @user6592730 Ok no problem.